# Scheme: reading files at macro expansion time

Tags: scheme

I'm using Chez Scheme and I'd like to introduce some top-level bindings based on the contents of a directory. The usage of this hypothetical macro might look like this:

```
(bind-files f "~/my-dir/")

;; Expanding to:
(begin (define f0 "~/my-dir/a.wav")
       (define f1 "~/my-dir/b.wav"))
```

I'm getting comfortable with `syntax-case`, `datum->syntax` and `with-syntax` as described in the [Scheme book's examples](http://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/compat.html#./compat:s29). But I can't imagine how one could create identifiers based on the result of something 'runtime-y' like `(directory-list "~/")` - is it even possible?

(By the way, this is for a live-coding musical application, so there's no need to comment that this is a bad idea for reliable software - it's for a very specific interactive context.)

Comment: This is probably possible to do but likely to have unexpected behavior. I'd suggest that macro expansion is the wrong time to do this, you would be much better to generate the list of definitions f0 f1 etc. at build time before invoking the scheme compiler.

Comment: As I said, it's intended to be used in a very interactive context, so generating at build time isn't too useful. Helpful to know that this might be a bad idea though. I have a sort of halfway-house working now, where we get the function `f` which takes indeces and returns a file-path. This might be acceptable.

Comment: if this needs to be done dynamically then how about doing `(define f (bind-files "~/my-dir"))` which defines `f` a to be function where `(f 0)` gives you the first file, `(f 1)` gives you the second file. This can easily be implemented using functions and no macros.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely a possible approach too. I just wanted to try this other way also to see what feels easiest when performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this macro:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs) (chezscheme))

(define-syntax bind-file
  (lambda (x)
    (define (name&file k dir)
      (define (->fn i)
        (string->symbol (string-append "f" (number->string i))))
      (let ((files (directory-list (syntax->datum dir))))
        (datum->syntax k (do ((i 0 (+ i 1)) (files files (cdr files))
                              (r '() (cons (list (->fn i) (car files)) r)))
                             ((null? files) r)))))
    (syntax-case x ()
      ((k dir)
       (string? (syntax->datum #'dir))
       (with-syntax ((((name file) ...) (name&file #'k #'dir)))
         #'(begin (define name file) ...))))))

(bind-file ".")

#|
;; depending on the number of files
f0 ... fn variables are defined.
|#
```

Comment: Ah interesting, so you can do normal procedure calls in `with-syntax`? Thanks very much for your help!